# Django 1.9. template inheritance. Block doesn't display

Tags: python, html, django, templates, inheritance

I have 2 html pages in my Django templates. I am trying to insert cats.html in index.html as a block, but nothing happens. No errors, no display.  I already looked in django documentation and in the youtube. Just can't understand where is problem

index.html:

```
    {% load static %}


<!DOCTYPE doctype html>
        <html class="no-js" lang="en">
         <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'items/index-style.css' %}" />

      <title>
       my site
      </title>


     </head>
     <body>
{% block cats %} 
{% endblock cats %}
 </body>
</html>
```

cats.html:

```
{% extends "index.html" %}

{% block cats %}

<div class="row column">
    <p class="lead">
     Категории товаров
    </p>
   </div>
   <div class="row small-up-1 medium-up-2 large-up-3">

        {% for category in categories %}



    <div class="column">
    <a href="/{{category.alias}}">

     <div class="callout">
      <p>
       {{category.name}}
      </p>
      <p>
       <img alt="image of a planet called Pegasi B" src="{{category.image}}"/>
      </p>
      <p class="lead">
      <!-- Цена: {{tovar.price}} -->
      </p>
      <p class="subheader">
       <!-- {{tovar.short_description}} -->
      </p>
     </div>
    </a>

    </div>


         {% endfor %}

   </div>

{% endblock cats %}
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
from django.template.loader import render_to_string


from items.models import *

# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    try:    
        categories = Category.objects.all()
    except: 
        raise Http404()
    context = {
        'categories':categories,
    }
    return render(request,"index.html",context)
```

Comment: Please show code rendering template.

Comment: The view is still referencing index.html, not cats.html

Comment: Oh, Thanks. It really works when i changed my views.py:  return render(request,"cats.html",context)/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

actually the problem is you use index.html as a base template 
and then inherit in your cats.html 
so you have to render cat.html to get the desired result [THIS IS HELPFUL FOR YOU](http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/template_extending/)

```
return render(request, 'cats.html', context)
```

thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the block name with template name. You are *not* inserting `cats.html` into `index.html` as you expect, but you are extending `index.html` in your `cats.html`. You should use your child template (`cats.html`) in your view, ie change the last line to:

```
return render(request, 'cats.html', context)
```